# Ajax Call Taking Too Long

Tags: magento2, ajax

In my .phtml i have:

```
require([
'jquery'
], function ($) {
 $.ajax({
        url: "get_shipment_info.php",
        type: "get", //send it through get method
        data: { 
            company: ManiFacturerName
        },
        success: function(response) {
},
        error: function(xhr) {
            console.log("ERR");
            //Delete the object
            var element = document.getElementById('shipment_info');
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        }
  });
});
```

The php file

```
url: "get_shipment_info.php",
```

is just `echo "1";`
The problem is i get the response after 7seconds. I dont know why...

Comment: It is an issue with your server response. Don't think  it is an issue with magento

Comment: How so the page loads fine its just the ajax call being slow?

Comment: This looks more like an infrastructure issue rather than magento, therefore more details about the setup should be included. for example, if you run the the cli that get_shipment_info.php - how long does it take to run.. that echo "1" is the only statement in the file or magento's bootstrap is included? etc..

Answer (score -1):

You can just set below code in your phtml file to use ajax, You have to change your customurl in below code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery"],function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var customurl = "<?php echo $this->getUrl().'frontname/index/index'?>";
            $.ajax({
                url: customurl,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    customdata1: 'test1',
                    customdata2: 'test2',
                },
            complete: function(response) {             
                country = response.responseJSON.default_country;
                state = response.responseJSON.state;         
                console.log(state+' '+country);   
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

inside your controller file **execute()** method,

```
<?php
 use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
 public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);

        $response = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_RAW);
        $response->setHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
        $country = 'india';
        $state = 'gujarat';
        $response->setContents(
            $this->_jsonHelper->jsonEncode(
                [
                    'default_country' => $country,
                    'state' => $state,
                ]
            )
        );
        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: could you be more specific this is for another example..

Comment: this is not working

Comment: any error show ?

Comment: i cant get it to working could you please be more spesific like, how do i link my custom url to execute method, also where my controller file is....